# Is it possible to filter Google search results on response headers?

Tags: google-search, headers

Is there any way to tell Google "give me all the results that contain some `response` header/value X?

For example, I would like to search for content on a topic, but only include results that have the header and value `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`.

Comment: That returns pages about CORS but not actual pages that have that header in its response

Comment: by header you mean what exactly?

Comment: The HTTP response header. When you make an HTTP request for a page, the response includes headers (not visible in the browser, without opening developer tools)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Google Search is not able to provide search results of that type, but there are other search engines which could pull this off like:

- **https://nerdydata.com/**
- **https://publicwww.com/**
- **https://searchcode.com/**

Comment: These are really cool! Thanks!

Comment: @rayray added one more